# List with sublists inside

Tags: python, list, random

I want to create a list made in this way :

1. the length of the list is a number that I decide, say s (pretty big, not exaggerated)
2. The entries are all zeroes, apart from one, which has value n
3. The entry with value n could be in the middle, but I want it to appear randomly in the list, i.e. if I run the program again (or with some kind of loop) it gives me a vector where the entry different from 0 is in another position. E.g. v1 = [0,0,n,0], v2 = [n,0,0,0], etc

How can I do that?

This is what I tried for a list s of size 4:

```
s = [0,0,0,0]
r = random.random()
intr = int(r*len(s))
s[intr] = n
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of your own attempt and explain what difficulties you are facing, please. SO is *not* a code writing service.

Comment: I advise you look into NumPy

Comment: You have `s` inner lists? Is `n` in each inner list? Are the inner lists always size 4?

Comment: Well the inner lists can be any size, the point is that I want  a random element to be equals to n, the others equal to 0

Comment: `import random; l = [0 for _ in range(4)]; ridx = random.randrange(0, len(l)); l[ridx] = 10; print(l)`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
>>> from random import randint
>>> n = 10
>>> a = [0]*n // initialise array a wwith exactly n zeros
>>> a
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>> i = randint(0,n-1) // get random number from 0 to n-1
>>> i
1
>>> a[i]=n //assign a[i] to n
>>> a
[0, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```